# How do I add a preloader to my game using flashDevelop?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop, preloader

Hi I have made a tile based game using a tutorial from this site http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011...m-game-part-1/ My game is complete but I want to add a preloader to it.

A little background for a hopefully better understanding.

FlashDevelop is where all of my as3 files and classes are and I can also test my game here and I works fine.

Flash CS6 is where I have only one scene "scene 1" with one frame on it, this frame has all of my tile based images ( movieClips ) and animations in squares, if I double click a movieClip ( for example "player" ) it will go inside and I have got lots of frames ( jumping, running etc ).

I can't test my game from here, It shows errors (scenes are NAN). I think that's normal not sure - maybe off topic anyway.

I have looked on the internet for a tutorial on preloaders suiting my situation but can't find any using flash with flashDevelop and AS3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a brand new project "Actionscript 3 with preloader", FD will generate you a preloader class *.as file, and a main class file with a `[frame]` directive in it. Copy the preloader *.as file into your current project, copy the directive from new project's Main.as into your project's Main.as, change the package name if needed in both places (in preloader's `getDefinitionByName()` call and in the directive - fully qualified class names required), add whatever visuals you want to your preloader class, and you're set.

The directive in my case looked like this:

```
[Frame(factoryClass="Geologist.Preloader")]
```

The package is `Geologist`, and the `startup()` function of the preloader was like this:

```
private function startup():void 
{
    var mainClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("Geologist.Main") as Class;
    var theStage:Stage = this.stage;
    theStage.addChild(new mainClass() as DisplayObject);
    theStage.removeChild(this);
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said but i get an error saying that some of my vars on my main.as are null. I will keep trying and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Of course, stage will be null. Get over that via `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event listener in the main class. Move constructor code in the listener and place `if (stage) init(null); else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);` as the only code of the constructor.

Comment: Thankyou I have no error's now, the screen goes blue for half a second witch is my stage background then the game appears, now just have to code my loading bar i think. When you said in your first answer about adding visuals did you mean for the loading bar and what you see when its loading or do i have to add all of my game images for it to load correctly ?

Comment: No, just add whatever you see fit to display loading status. Everything else is already available through main class.

Comment: ok cool, it's all done now :) thankyou for taking time to help me.